# data lost with both ckeditor and tinymce editor in asp.net mvc5 with very large texts/images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, tinymce

I am facing a strange behavior with ckeditor/tinymce editor in asp.net mvc5, razor application. Sometimes when I save very large data above 10 mb of size it fails to store data, It truncates some large part of it, and does not give any error, the behavior is strange, and I am not able to find any solution, I changes my editor from ckeditor to tinymce, but the problem remained same.

Even the behavior is not static, sometimes it works even with much larger data, but sometimes it fails all of a sudden without any error.

I am not sure where is the problem, with editor, or with MVC controller function in receiving such large data etc, but again sometimes it goes well and sometimes it misbehaves that's what is crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further analysis we found that JavaScript editors like tinymce of CKEditor are not capable of handling such large data and that's why it was doing such strange behavior. To test this further we deployed our application on a server with better processor, and more Ram than our existing server, and then the things went well. The behavior of dramatically losing data while posting has been strange for us, at least it should give some error or exception, or should not work all together.